# Best way to manage webhooks

Tags: apex, webhooks

I am currently developing integration that syncs entities between salesforce and another CRM.

My issue is, that to be able to apply changes in real time i need webhooks to do so. I created ApexTrigger that executes my Apex class which dumps entity to json then sends it to specified url.

The problem is that this method works like charm on non production enviroments and i am unable to replicate this methodology on production enviroments because of error (i cant directly create apex on prod env).

What i found out is that i have basically 2 options:

- Package my Apex and install it on target space: this approach have big issue, because i need to create ApexTriggers for CustomEntities.
- Create Sandbox, create my apex class and triggers there and then deploy to production: this approach seems that it could work, but dont know if it will be possible by using API only.

Could somebody tell me how to do this properly ?

This is example what i am working with

Apex class

```
public class Webhook implements HttpCalloutMock{

    public static String jsonContent(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
         return '{}'
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(String url, String content) {

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        # fills request body and headers ...
        h.send(req);
    }
}
```

Apex trigger sample

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after delete, after update, after insert) {
    String url = 'URL';
    String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
    Webhook.callout(url, content);
}
```

Comment: For clarification, i was using httpCalloutMock so when i test callout method i have if statement which i did not include: if (Test.isRunningTest()) { Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Webhook()); }

Comment: But anyways, i feel like i wrongly worded my question. I want to know which method of deploying such classes and triggers you think is best out of the 2 mentioned or propably propose other solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webhook callout will work OK with small numbers of records, for the immediate need. I think the other parts of your question can be answered by looking at declarative features.

> How do I replicate this methodology on production?

Idea (1) [Outbound Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm) are robust XML webhooks. They are bulk-safe, Salesforce supported, you can set them up manually or deploy them using Metadata API. It relies on your other CRM being able to read and acknowledge the payload however.

> How do I create ApexTriggers for custom entities?

Idea (2) Instead of Apex Triggers, consider lifting your HTTP logic into Flow:

- Invocable Action wraps your Apex in a little GUI (eg for the webhook endpoint)
- This example uses `SObject`, one code supports all entities, not only Accounts
- End users love flow because the solution is customizable and self-documenting

Here is an example similar to your current code. But now your Webhook class appears as a custom action in flow. It can be added to a Record Triggered flow on any object.

You can install the apex+tests here: [/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tJX0000002f5V](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tJX0000002f5V)

[image: Jan-Balucha-Webhook]

```
public class Webhook
{
    @InvocableMethod(callout=true)
    static public void invoke(List<Request> requests)
    {
        for (Request request : requests)
        {
            HttpRequest post = new HttpRequest();
            post.setMethod('POST');
            post.setEndpoint(request.Endpoint);
            post.setBody(Json.serialize(request.Record));
            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) new Http().send(post);
        }
    }

    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true) public String Endpoint;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true) public SObject Record;
    }
}

@IsTest class WebhookTest
{
    @IsTest static void testInvoke()
    {
        Webhook.Request request = new Webhook.Request();
        request.endpoint = 'https://www.example.com';
        request.record = new Account(Name = 'ACME'); // arrange
        Webhook.invoke(new List<Webhook.Request>{request}); // act
        System.assertEquals(0, Limits.getCallouts()); // assert
    }
}
```

Idea (3) Use [Streamscript](https://www.streamscript.com/) to send the webhooks

- Same idea, but you compose the HTTP callout in Flow Builder
- Choose the 'Run Asynchronously' path on the Record-Triggered Flow
- Use the [Bulk](https://www.streamscript.com/docs#Bulk_and_mass_actions) directive to transmit 200 records in 1 request, (like your existing webhook)
- Your user clicks [Debug] as many times as needed to experiment with entry criteria etc

[image: Streamscript Outbound Webhook]

One webhook can transmit very helpful key events, or it could mean a bunch of expectations and error-handling mechanisms if not fit for purpose. Hopefully the essential goal is to make it work, then refine over time as you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. i will propably use outbound messages as it doesn t require anything to be installed on salesforce instance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using triggers try using `change data capture` and write a subscriber trigger on CDC.

As CDC subscriber triggers will work after the data is committed it doesn't block your DML Operation `(async)`

Also salesforce doesn't impose any limit on cdc events for subscriber triggers

Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm